# HTML is not rendered [Twig] / [Slim]

Tags: php, html, twig, slim

I am using twig as templating engine but my html is not rendering. All is displayed with the HTML tags itself.

[Data from Database can be found by clicking here](http://www.beetxt.com/Ms7/)

I searched SO and got many posts that provides solution but none worked for me

below are the solutions:

1. Use below code [**not working**]

   ```
   {{ detailArticle.artdesc|raw }}

    or

   {% autoescape false %}
     {{ detailArticle.artdesc }}
   {% endautoescape %}
   ```
2. Use filter and autoload like below [**not working**]

   ```
   $app->view = new \Slim\Views\Twig();
   $app->view->setTemplatesDirectory("application/view");
   $app->view->parserOptions = array(
      'debug' => 'true',
      'auto_reload' => true,
      'autoescape' => true
   );
   $app->view->parserExtensions = array(new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension());
   ```
3. Clear Twig cache [**I do not have CLI on cPanel, so not sure how to do this**]

   ```
   rm -rf app/cache/*  OR rm -rf app/cache/prod/twig OR app/console cache:clear --env=prod
   ```

None of the solutions working for me. Please guide.

Data is displayed in same way you will see on the link mentioned above.

My composer.json is as below

```
{
 "name":"panique/mini2",
 "homepage":"https://github.com/panique/mini2",
 "license":"MIT",
 "require":{
    "php":">=5.3.0",
    "slim/slim": "~2.6",
    "slim/views": "~0.1",
    "twig/twig": "~1.16",
    "panique/pdo-debug": "0.2",
    "panique/php-sass": "~1.0",
    "matthiasmullie/minify": "~1.3"
 },
"autoload":{
    "psr-4":{
        "Mini\\": "Mini"
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with the [verbatim](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html#verbatim) tag?

Comment: How to use this...

Comment: hi @gags i post an example in my answer. Let me know

Comment: sorry @gags not your case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this same problem a few months ago.
You need write this in your php:

```
$escaper = new Twig_Extension_Escaper(false);
$app->view->addExtension($escaper);
```

My code

```
require_once 'path_to_Twig/Autoloader.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('path_to_views/');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array());

$escaper = new Twig_Extension_Escaper(false);
$twig->addExtension($escaper);

echo $twig->render($view_name, $data_to_view);
```

Steps with your code

1. Download: http://pear.twig-project.org/get/Twig-1.24.0.tgz
2. Uncompress and place in you proyect.
3. Write this in your file:

```
 require 'vendor/autoload.php'; 

 // Initialize Slim (the router/micro framework used) 
 $app = new \Slim\Slim(array( 
 'mode' => 'production' 
 )); 

 require_once 'path_to_Twig/Autoloader.php'; //Substitute the Twig path, the path to the uncompress files in the project 
 Twig_Autoloader::register(); 

 $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('path_to_views/'); //Substitute with the path with the html files 
 $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array()); 

 $escaper = new Twig_Extension_Escaper(false); 
 $twig->addExtension($escaper); 

 echo $twig->render($view_name, $data_to_view); //First the name of the view html file, data that you want pass to the view in one array
```

You need put all this whe you want render the view in the controller, that is to say, you substitute your code by this.

Comment: Call to undefined method Slim\Views\Twig::addExtension() is the error

Comment: But you have created the twig object and addExtension is a method. it's much strange that you can create the object but not access to the method.

Comment: Where this `Twig_Extension_Escaper` can be located

Comment: I wrote in the solution all my code, I use this code for all projects. If you use namespaces with Slimframework, try to use Twig directly, like my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109426/discussion-between-miguel-jimenez-and-gags).

Comment: Now i am in somewhat confusion that is there something extra needed to be done to display content saved by CKEditor.

Comment: I added another solution, and if you do well this i'm sure that it works

Comment: Do you think that it is something to do with CKeditor output?

Comment: i really appreciate your concern and efforts :) I think i did it right and now when i am rendering it gives me error `Message: Undefined variable: twig` .. This is really frustrating

Comment: I am accepting your answer as you did right ways but actually issue  was with my editor that was used to add content

Comment: I used a lot of times Twig + tinymce and this worked perfect. Tinymce is a similar editor to CKEditor

Comment: I'm so grateful for this answer! :D

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue and resolved it by adding the Twig_Extnesion_Escaper:

```
$v = new \Slim\Views\Twig(__DIR__ . '/../../templates', [
    'cache' => __DIR__ . '/../../templates/twigcache'
]);
$v->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Escaper());
```